# Crash when saving data to Realm in background thread. | iOS | Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    RccContactController.shared.updateDbForAppUsers(contactModels: contacts)
                  }
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    RccContactController.shared.updateSyncStatus(lastCount : lastIndex)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        ContactDataStore.shared.updateContacts(withAppUsers: contacts)
                        if let safeDelegate = RccContactController.shared.delegate {
                            safeDelegate.syncedPhonebookContact(contacts: restContacts, appUsers: cont)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

What's happening above:

- retrieving the synced contacts data from the server via Socket
- Update App users in DB in a background thread
- Update sync status in DB in a background thread and after the process notifies my controller through a delegate.

Sometimes I'm getting a crash in the second thread.

> enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (thread 1)

What's wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Realm does use the CoreData internally and Apple states that database persistent data storage(add, update) should be performed on the main queue.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Not to disagree, but where did you get that information from? I am curious. Also, Realm works perfectly fine on background queues - see the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and also [Using Realm Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads). You may want to take a look at [Using Core Data in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background) as well.

Comment: Yeah !! Even that's what I am doing here. Performing my CRUD operation with a background queue. However, we need to take care of the scope of the properties within a particular thread but it should not be a mandate to do these operations on the main queue.

Answer (score 3):

**Do like this:**

```
  DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    RccContactController.shared.updateSyncStatus(lastCount : lastIndex)                              
    ContactDataStore.shared.updateContacts(withAppUsers: contacts)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let safeDelegate = RccContactController.shared.delegate {
            safeDelegate.syncedPhonebookContact(contacts: restContacts, appUsers: cont)
        }
    }
}
```

**General Example:**

```
  DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
        let obj = realm.resolve(wrappedObj)

        try realm.write {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Callback or Update UI in Main thread
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        //Callback or Update UI in Main thread
    }
}
```

Perform only UI Operation in `DispatchQueue.main.async` rest of keep in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks. Also, does it matter if I write the same code in two different background threads as I posted above?

Comment: It's doesn't matter. We can write multiple background queue with multiples operation.

Comment: The only difference between my implementation and your suggestion is that you have put out the following statement outside the main thread.
ContactDataStore.shared.updateContacts(withAppUsers: contacts)
However, I was performing some UI dependent task with this and therefore I used the former way. Now, I've removed this method call completely from this whole block. I want to see if this was actually the only problem as this crash was very rare to occur.

Comment: Can you please help me on this question as well. Same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700998/enqueued-from-com-apple-main-thread-thread-1-crash-ios-swift-4-1